# Review privileges suspended in Triage for one question which is already closed

Tags: support, triage, review-suspension

I see my review privileges have been suspended for the triage verification of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27466958).

I chose 'Needs community edit' as I believed the question can be made answerable after a few tweaks. But I am banned from reviewing, even though the question is closed.

[image]

Can you please review the task ?

Comment: @RoshinRaphel What edits can the community make that clarifies the question?

Comment: You commented because it required an edit by the author. Why didn’t you choose that option?  It criticizing you, just trying to figure out what could be improved in the review process.

Comment: @yivi When I reviewed the post, the option was not Community edit, it was `Required editing`, so I thought it meant for the OP also.

Comment: Yes, but you had a review suspension notice telling you that on Aug 22, which you read. If you still did not understand what "Required editing" meant you could have asked. There was a link to a resource and the resource had a link to a chatroom.

Comment: Ok, let’s hope the new labels do make a difference in the reviewers experience.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Yes, but It is now that I get the difference

Comment: @RoshinRaphel - You selected the incorrect option, this wasn’t the first time, did you ask about your first review suspension less than 2 months ago (approximately)?  The question didn’t mean even minimum guidelines for a question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's the next value in the following sequence? 6, 10, 3...

There's no way to know without the OP telling us is there? That means the question needs to be closed till that happens.

How are we to create columns? With spaces or commas or something else? There's no sample output.

Ideally the OP should show us what they've done to solve this problem in python and where they are stuck so we can see what they are missing. Can they not read the file, not split it up, not write it out again? That alone might give us a clue as to where they are getting the mysterious values from.